# Remove two subdirectories from url with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get rid of some subdirectories on my website. Currently when I need to access user settings I use this `username.mywebsite.com/public/user/settings.php` and I want it to look like `username.mywebsite.com/settings.php`. In my root directory a have a htaccess file with the following:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/user`

`RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /public/user/$1`

and it's not working. Also, do I have to modify the html href like this `<a href="/settings.php">`? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the leading `/` in your regex pattern. The slash is stripped off when URI is sent through rules in an htaccess file. Also, you should instead check to see if the destination exists before rewriting into the `/public/user/` directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/user
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/user%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/user%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/user/$1 [L]
```

> Also, do I have to modify the html href like this `<a href="/settings.php">`?

Yes, the rule only works in one direction, regex pattern *to* target. Never the other way around. So you need to make sure your content has the URLs that you want to use.