# Remove subdirectories from URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get rid of some subdirectories on my website.

I tried this link [Remove two subdirectories from url with mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644016/remove-two-subdirectories-from-url-with-mod-rewrite) but it does not work with my case.

Actually i have this structure : `www.mywebsite.com/fr/news/index.html` and I want it to look like `www.mywebsite.com/index.html`.

In my root directory a have a htaccess file with the following:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|es|pt)/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+fr/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|es|pt)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^fr/)^(.*)/$ /fr/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|es|pt)/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.html(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|es|pt)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fr/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

What would the change to do to make it work ?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Are you asking how to make the site default to the French version if no other other language is explicitly specified in the URL?

Comment: No, sorry. I would "only" hide fr and news subdirectories in the URL to show www.mywebsite.com/index.html.

Comment: — And if they wanted the English version, then they would still go to `/en/news/index.html`? So it is only the French site you want to change?

Comment: Not only the french site, also other language. Thanks for your help

Comment: So if they ask for `/index.html` they should get what? The French page or the English (or Spanish or Portugese) page?

Comment: Hi Quentin. So the index.html will be only for the french page.

Comment: So what did you mean by "also other language"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this structure:
>
> ```
> www.mywebsite.com/fr/news/index.html
> ```
>
> and I want it to look like
>
> ```
> www.mywebsite.com/index.html
> ```

Without knowing more, I'd suggest placing this in your root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/(.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1
```

The regex reads as:

- from the start, find one or more characters that aren't a forward slash
- then a forward slash
- then one or more characters that aren't a forward slash
- then a forward slash
- then capture all the remaining characters

Comment: Hi Rounin. I will try your solution. Thanks for your support

Comment: Sorry Ronin , I made a mistake !

Comment: Happy to help @Laurent! If you want to make the segments of the regex more specific, you can do that quite easily... for instance, if you want to specifically focus on the `fr/` folder, you could replace `[^\/]+\/` with `fr\/`.

Comment: To be clear my question is: How to use .htaccess to hide multiple directories in a url ?

Comment: We need to clarify because I'm not sure what you mean by "hide". Do you want to type `www.mywebsite.com/fr/news/index.html` into the browser and for the browser to display the page at `www.mywebsite.com/index.html`... or... do you want to type `www.mywebsite.com/index.html` into the browser and for the browser to display the page at `www.mywebsite.com/fr/news/index.html`? If you want to type in `www.mywebsite.com/fr/news/index.html` and you _still_ want to see that page, *but* you want the browser URI to change to `www.mywebsite.com/index.html`, I'm not sure that's possible...

Comment: @Ronin, my structure is : `root www --> folder fr--> folder news`. Into the folder fr i have a `hyperlink index.html` that point in `the folder news`. So when i click on index.html the url display `www.mywebsite.com/fr/news/index.html` and i would like `www.mywebsite.com/index.html`. It's possible ? Thanks very much

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/fr/news/index.html http://www.mywebsite.com/index.html [R=301,L]` will permanently redirect your browser from `www.mywebsite.com/fr/news/index.html` to `www.mywebsite.com/index.html`.